# Injective and order-preserving ring homomorphisms are unique.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let  $X$ and $Y$ be two ordered rings (i.e, they satisfy the order properties). Let $<_{X}$ and $<_{Y}$ be the strict partial orders on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a ring homomorphism which is injective and order-preserving, i.e 
$$\forall x\, \forall y\, (x<_{X}y \implies f(x)<_{Y}f(y) ).$$ 
Then prove that this map is unique.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that statement is true. Consider any ordered ring $R$, and take
$S=R[X]$, with the order such that the sign of $P\in R[X]$ is the sign of its leading coefficient.

Then the morphism $S\to S$ induced by $X\mapsto X^2$ is injective and order-preserving, but is not the identity.